# Powershell not executing from CMD (Batch) script

Tags: powershell, batch-file

There are quite some questions asked already regarding this issue, but none of the answers resolved mine.

I wrote following batch script:

```
powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass  -file "./myps.ps1"
```

I saved the file as `autorun.cmd`

Whenever I double-click the cmd file, nothing happens, CLI quickly shows up and closes but powershell was not executed.

If I run the same command directly in CLI, it works.

I am really confused on what's going on here. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Append a pause command to the batch to be able to see possible error messages. What about using a full path to the script file?

Comment: Full path did not help. I added PAUSE and SLEEP but none did any change, window closed quickly as before.

Comment: It **does** work here. Maybe an AntVirus program is interfering with the autorun.cmd - try again after renaming. I'm in doubt this is a programming related question - and is better suited on [SU]

Comment: First rule of debugging a batch file is to actually open up a command prompt and execute the batch file instead of using your mouse. This way you will see any verbose error messages

Comment: If `pause` doesn't help, maybe the file associations for `.cmd` files (batch files) are set up incorrectly. Run `Get-ChildItem -EA Ignore hkcu:\software\classes\cmdfile\shell\open, hklm:\software\classes\cmdfile\shell\open`; the (first) result should show command `"%1" %*` as the `(default)`  property value.

Comment: what is your association for `.cmd` files?

Answer (score 0):

Saving it as a `.bat` extension will fix it. Like you, I was never able to get a `.cmd` file to work as a batch file as well.

Answer (score 0):

So, hi and welcome to this platform...
I try run this powershel code above, that convert ansi to unicode file, by bat file using your command inside the bat:

```ps1
Set-Location ".\"
Get-Content 'ansi.txt' | Set-Content -Encoding unicode 'outunicode.txt'
```

And all running fine, my bat call to execute .ps1 code (copied from you to test propose), above the code inside bat file, like your code:

```bat
powershell.exe -executionpolicy bypass -file "./myps.ps1"
```

All run OK, no error, and the result file OK too!

So, this make me suggest to you, that maybe you need try running the bat file direct in your command line for to be able to see possible error message, and filling if this is a bat/powershell/security/other error, and, if possible, post/share the content `.ps1` file, I'm 100% sure, that here are someone (a lot of them) will be capable help you precisely and quickly. Sorry my English.